# Recover a MySQL database from files after upgrading into new version of XAMPP

Tags: mysql, database, xampp

I have a problem with a MySQL database that I haven’t been able to solve no matter how much I tried, either with internet guides or with free tools. I really don’t want to pay hundreds of dollars to a company so please, if anyone knows of a solution, help me because I’m desperate.

I was running XAMPP 7.1.22 where I had said database and I decided to install XAMPP 7.2.10 without backing up the database. After that, the site wasn’t working so I figured the problem was the database. And indeed PHPMyAdmin wouldn’t recognize it. I reinstalled the previous version of XAMPP and the database was there but unfortunately I could only see the tables. The tables themselves were empty though. So no dump procedure worked and neither the site. Now all I have left is the folder with the database which contains all the .frm and the .ibd files, an .opt file, a .myd file and a .myi file. I also have the ibdata1 file.

Any ideas or suggestions? Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: To double check, I would try to log manually into the database and query the tables. If they really are gone, and neither your database or your server have backups, then your data might be gone. You might try contacting the company your server is hosted through, a lot of times they keep backups that you can pay them to restore.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately the database is stored locally. In addition I checked with an online, paid service and I know that I can restore it but that is what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Well after waiting and trying a lot, I decided to roll back the site and add the missing content again. Thanks for your time.